# Log outgoing ip addresses from android device

Tags: android, ip-address

I need to figure out which ip addresses/domains an app is connecting to on my android phone. Is there an easy way to do this?

I've tried vpns but I can't figure out where it would log that information or if it even does.

Comment: I've tried wireguard and openvpn. Neither one logs the information I want as far as I can tell. I've tried netstat and nethogs but I can't see the connections.

Comment: "For topics related to Android, use Android-specific tags such as android-intent, android-activity, android-adapter, etc. For questions other than development or programming, but related to the Android framework, use this link: https://android.stackexchange.com."